# C# Windows Form (Adding New Controls At Running)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

I have started new windows form apllication and I want to add some Control instance when I press any button.(I want program to add two more button if I press AddButton).

Comment: Create controls in designer and set their visibility to false. Then after pressing a button, set visibility to true.

Answer (score 3):

You need at least some `x`,`y` cordinates to place it, then you can check the button's properties and change it however you want.

```
private void createButton(string name, int x, int y)
{
    // Create button
    Button btn = new Button();

    // Set button name
    btn.Name = name;

    // Set location
    btn.Location = new Point(x, y);

    //Hook our button up to our generic button handler
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);

    // Add it to the main panel
    // panel1 is your application name
    panel1.Controls.Add(
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is the handler of the button that we created");
}
```

Then in the main button that creates the buttons you can call the button like this:

```
createButon("some name", 5,5);
```